# MVC Routing: route precedence not working as expected

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I study a MVC sample I have a controller Home and a action Index.

I have the following routing registration:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapRoute("MyRoute", "{controller}/{action}");

    routes.MapRoute("MyOtherRoute", "App/{action}",
        new { controller = "Home" });
}
```

As I understood, if the requested route does not match (OR THE MATCH GIVES A NULL RESULT?!), the framework will continue to search in the rest of the routes...

By eg, if I will navigate to the `/App/Index`, I expect that I will be redirected to the `Index` method of `Home` Controller.

That is the case, but only in the "MyRoute" is defined *after* "MyOtherRoute" or "MyRoute" is missing at all. But as is presented before, I got a `HTTP 404`.

Why this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As found in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.ASPX#how_urls_are_matched_to_routes) after some researches:

> When a match occurs, no more routes are evaluated.

Apparently, there is no difference if that match gave or not the results...

Answer (score 1):

MVC is validating the routes from the top and your first route is valid for `/App/Index`. It is not checked if the route leads to an existing controller / action.

You must add the route so that the more specific routes are at the beginning, then it will work as you need it.

Comment: it matches from the top, but the first match gives a null result(App controller does not exist), so it should go on searching?!

Comment: No, MVC will not go on searching, it will display `HTTP 404` like you got. Just change the order and it should work.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, changing the order works, so this is not a problem. As for me, it will be better if once no result is obtained from a match, the system continue to search matches...